# Updating Identical Access Tables

Tags: vba, ms-access, sql-update

I need to update my original Access table (keep historical data by primary key) with new data table.  It has 30+ fields.  How can I create the update query for every field without manually typing every field in query design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your "new data table" has the same structure as that of your original table, your `append` query can omit the column specification and be written as:

```sql
insert into [original table] select * from [new data table]
```

If instead you are using an `update` query, then to my knowledge it is not possible to update all fields in the table without specifying the field names following the `SET` clause.

This can obviously be accomplished by iterating over the fields in a recordset using VBA, but you'll sacrifice performance for the sake of saving yourself some typing.

Comment: Thank you Lee for this code I will use it, but I already 'Append' new data by the primary key, however much of the original data (historical) changes periodically (its a product master list) and I need to keep the properties of the products (categories etc.) updated. Is the a quick solution (code) to updating all the fields with code all at once?  Thank you!!

Comment: @nancmadi You're welcome. Following your additional information, I have updated my answer above.

Comment: THANK YOU SO VERY MUCH, I truly appreciate the time you have taken to confirm my thoughts and current findings (nothing) LOL... ok.. I will push on and create my query as I know it today to work.. thanks for your support.

Comment: @nancmadi You're most welcome (sorry to have been the bearer of bad news - I'd happily be corrected if there was a way to achieve this!) If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark the answer as the solution (and upvote if you feel appropriate), so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site. Refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are unsure how to do this. Thanks!